# Why isn't this Silverlight transition working?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0, transition

I'm trying to grasp some Silverlight animation basics by creating a simple (I'd imagine) transition.

**Expected behaviour:**

I have a simple `UserControl` representing an input form with (currently) two states - for testing purposes it's really simplified - a few buttons which don't do anything and a background to make the states more distinct.

The idea is to create a "rotating" effect (using `ScaleX` transformation) when switching states.

**The problem:**

I *could* create a separate animation for a transition from each state to each other state (in the current case of 2 states it'd be very simple) but I'm thinking - if there are more states and I want to be able to change from any of them to any other, then such an approach is hardly ideal.

So I wanted to make use of the generic transitions to and from states, and created the XAML as defined below. The issue is that when switching from one state to the other, for the first half of the transition (0:0:0 -> 0:0:0.2) the state I'm transitioning FROM is invisible (white background, no buttons).

Why is that? How should I create this transition?

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="TransitionTest.UserControl1"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480" Background="White">
<Grid x:Name="grid1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="VisualState1">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="State1">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="VisualState1" GeneratedDuration="0">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="State1">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="VisualState2">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1">
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="1">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="State2">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition From="VisualState2" GeneratedDuration="0">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1" d:IsOptimized="True">
                            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="State2">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualState1">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="State1">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualState2">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="State2">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
        <ei:ExtendedVisualStateManager/>
    </VisualStateManager.CustomVisualStateManager>
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="3" Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Grid x:Name="State1" Margin="0" Background="#FF6CB5E8" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Width="200"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="State2" Margin="0" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="#FF80DE5C">
                <Button Content="Button" Margin="2,0,3,203" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,203,0,0" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.333,1.273" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Here's the CS file, if it's in any way important:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TransitionTest
{
    [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "VisualStateGroup", Name = "VisualState1")]
    [TemplateVisualState(GroupName = "VisualStateGroup", Name = "VisualState2")]
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "VisualState1", false);
        }

        public bool State
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(StateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for State.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(false, State_Changed));

        private static void State_Changed(DependencyObject dObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = dObject as UserControl1;

            if (control.State)
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, "VisualState2", true);
            else
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, "VisualState1", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not good at these transitions topic but when I compare yours and mine I see I haven't got a storyboard under "VisualTransition" element. Instead I have a TransitionEffect. I think DiscreteObjectKeyFrame are really discrete. It doesn't complete middle frames for you. But i.e. ColorAnimation has a transition itself.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz Well, I've created the above code using Blend and only Blend...

Comment: As you see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc964288(v=vs.95).aspx there is no transition for DiscreteObjectKeyFrame you will see collapse and visible operations 0.2sn later. I think blend is not as stable as Macromedia's(now Adobe's) Flash. It sometimes cause catastrophic errors. You should manage well. All the best !